# WSO2is Use SOAP services with Access Token

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

It's possible to use an access token generated from `/oauth2/` endpoint and use in SOAP calls?

For now, I use the admin user for the tenant domain for creating and get users, but I think it is better to use the access token for a logged user based in permissions to create new users.

I already try to add a header in SOAP call as follows: `Authorization: Bearer <access-toke>`, but `Authentication failure` display message.
I try to change the url `https://identity.com/t/mydomain/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/`

Answer (score 5):

SOAP APIs in WSO2 Identity Server cannot be authenticated with Bearer tokens. They can be authenticated with Basic authentication and cookies.

Comment: Thank you @Hasanthi, where can I found docs for use cookies for authenticate ?

Comment: From the AuthenticationAdmin admin service you can obtain the jsessionid. Based on the jsessionid you can invoke the service. Please refer https://medium.com/@maheeka/wso2-admin-services-c61b7d856272

Comment: Oh man... That's so annoying... :( Thanks for the answer though!